# Vim: How to make AutoComplPop, Snipmate, SuperTab work together?

Tags: vim

1. AutoComplPop pops choices automatically. I love it very much.
2. SuperTab allows me to set the function of `<Tab>`. I always set as follows.
   `let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "<c-n>"`
   By doing so, If AutoComplPop pops many choices, pressing `<Tab>` can select the next choice.
3. Snipmate implements some of TextMate's snippets features in Vim.

If I install them together, some problems happened.

For example, when I type `cl` and press `<Tab>` for the first time in test.py. Snipmate works. However, when I type `cl` for the second time, AutoComplPop pops choices including `class`. If I press `<Tab>`, it selects the choice named `class` and Snipmate doesn't work.

So, any solutions to make AutoComplPop, Snipmate, SuperTab work together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SuperTab seems to be the outlier, here: its purpose is *not* to override the `<Tab>` key but to provide completion using that `<Tab>` key as a trigger (with an underlying logic roughly similar to ACP's).

You seem to use that plugin in a very contrived manner IMO.

This mapping allows you to use `<Tab>` to select the next item in the completion menu:

```
inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<C-g>u\<Tab>"
```

It is inspired by [this Vim wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_Vim_completion_popup_menu_work_just_like_in_an_IDE) which I recommend.

Comment: Thanks. SuperTab + ACP works fine. But, SuperTab, ACP and Snipmate conflict. Your solution cannot make Snipmate work fine. Currently, I only use Snipmate + ACP, and use `CTRL + N` to select the next item in the completion menu. But I still want to use `<Tab>` to select the next item.

Comment: My solution precisely does that and totally removes the need for SuperTab which you seem to use wrongly anyway. I, too, use snipmate and ACP and this mapping works well in my testing: ACP does completion just fine and I can `<Tab>` through the suggestions while snipmate works perfectly.

Comment: I remove SuperTab and try it again. Pressing `<Tab>` can select the next item without Snipmate. If I use ACP and Snipmate together, when ACP pops the completion menu and I press `<Tab>`, there is a tab (4 blanks long) in my code. I notice that snipmate.vim has a piece of code. `if pumvisible()  ... "close completion menu and call feedkeys("\<tab>")`. Which version of snipmate do you use?

Comment: I use the original Snipmate by msanders.

Comment: So do I. I remove other plugins, and only use ACP and Snipmate. I still cannot use `<Tab>` to select the next item. I don't know why? I run the following code to see what is mapped to `<Tab>`: `:verbose imap <tab>`. I get that: `<Tab>       * <C-R>=TriggerSnippet()<CR>
`, which is modified by `~/.vim/bundle/snipmate.vim/after/plugin/snipMate.vim`

Comment: 1. Your usage of SuperTab is wrong: the fact that it modifies ACP's behavior is a side effect and basing your workflow on a side effect is  a *very* bad idea. My advice is to drop that plugin entirely. 2. The mapping I gave you works perfectly here. Snipmate works as it should: `<tab>` expands a snippet and ACP works as it should too, with `<Tab>` used to select the next suggestion.

Comment: I know what you mean and the meaning of `inoremap`. When you answer my question, I remove SuperTab entirely. But I have tried many times and failed following your instructions. I don't know why. But I will try it again. Anyway, thank you very much.